# Why is it possible to set a 2d array even if setter not implemented

Tags: c#, getter-setter

Why is it possible to set a 2d array even if the setter not implemented?

Here's my code.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var obj = new TestObj();
    obj.qwe[0, 0] = 6;
    obj.asd = 7; //error
    Console.WriteLine(obj.qwe[0, 0]); //6
}

public class TestObj
{
    public int[,] qwe { get; } = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
    public int asd { get; } = 4;
}
```

Comment: It stops you writing `obj.qwe = ....`

Comment: The same applies to 1D arrays also. The behavior you see is due to the design of the class and how C# functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is it possible to set a 2d array even if the setter not implemented?

Because you aren't setting the property, you are updating an item in the array.

For example, this wouldn't compile:

```
obj.qwe = new int[0, 0];
```

In your code, you are calling `get` to obtain a reference to the array, and updating the item at index 0, 0:

```
obj.qwe[0, 0] = 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

The property `qwe` is returning the reference to the array contents. The same applied to 1D or multi-dim arrays. All arrays in C# follow reference semantics

Consider the following

```
int[,] temp = obj.qwe;  // property get
temp[0,0] = 6;
// obj.qwe[0,0] == 6
```

To prevent this from happening you need to create a wrapper class to the 2D array and implement an indexer.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntArray obj = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
        int x = obj[0, 0];  // ok, getter defined
        obj[0, 0] = 10;     // error, no setter defined
        int[,] objCopy = obj;  // assignment to int[,] makes a copy
        objCopy[0, 0] = 10; // ok to modify copy
    }
}
```

Use the integer array wrapper class below:

```
public class IntArray
{
    readonly int[,] data;

    public IntArray(int rows, int columns)
    {
        this.data = new int[rows, columns];
        this.Rows = rows;
        this.Columns = columns;
    }
    public IntArray(int[,] data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.Rows = data.GetLength(0);
        this.Columns = data.GetLength(1);
    }
    public int this[int row, int column]
    {
        // indexer getter
        get => data[row, column];
    }
    public int Rows { get; }
    public int Columns { get; }
    public int[,] ToArray()
    {
        int[,] copy = new int[Rows, Columns];
        Array.Copy(data, copy, data.Length);
        return copy;
    }
    public static implicit operator IntArray(int[,] array)
        => new IntArray(array);
    public static implicit operator int[,](IntArray obj)
        => obj.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is the case has already been answered by others.

To make the property read only I would suggest creating your own class for 2D arrays. This allow you to implement a read only interface, and it is fairly easy to do:

```
    public interface IReadOnlyArray2D<out T>
    {
        T this[int x, int y] { get; }
    }
    public class MyArray2D<T> : IReadOnlyArray2D<T>
    {
        public int Width { get; }
        public int Height { get; }
        public T[] Data { get; }

        public MyArray2D(int width, int height )
        {
            this.Width = width;
            this.Height = height;
            Data = new T[width * height];
        }
        public T this[int x, int y]
        {
            get => Data[y * Width + x];
            set => Data[y * Width + x] = value;
        }
    }
```

There are other advantages of using a regular 1D array as the backing storage:

- Sometimes you only want to process all items, and do not care about the x/y coordinates.
- Multidimensional arrays can sometimes be slow if it is used incorrectly.
- Interoperability is often easier since more systems use 1D arrays or pointers when exchanging data.
- creating a multidimensional array like `new T[width, height]` will store it in column-major order, while most image-like data is usually stored row-major order.